# Search a commit by commit message in VSCode or Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to search Git History to find a commit based on the commit message (not header or headline) in VSCode or Visual Studio IDE? Please help me if any extensions are available for this requirement.

Comment: dont know abt vscode, but this is doable with the git cli...

Comment: @leoOrion, how would you do it with git cli?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) in VsCode you're able to search through commits.[image]